# How to take test.salesforce.com while deployment as salesforce login url for api connection logic app?

Tags: azure, salesforce, azure-logic-apps, salesforce-service-cloud

In logic app i'm using `salesforce connector` after deployment i observe for `api connection` while authorize i'm getting `login.salesforce.com` but i want it as `test.salesforce.com` which is sandbox url.

Is there any way to define that ?

below parameters are there in logic app currently unable to see anything to define url.

```
    "parameters": {
      "$connections": {
        "value": {
          "SalesforceConnection": {
            "id": "[concat(subscription().id, '/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/', 'southcentralus', '/managedApis/', 'salesforce')]",
            "connectionId": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/connections', parameters('salesforce_conn_name'))]",
            "connectionName": "[parameters('salesforce_conn_name')]"
          }
        }
      }
    }

    {
  "type": "MICROSOFT.WEB/CONNECTIONS",
  "apiVersion": "2016-06-01",
  "name": "[parameters('salesforce_conn_name')]",
  "location": "southcentralus",
  "properties": {
    "api": {
      "id": "[concat(subscription().id, '/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/', 'southcentralus', '/managedApis/', 'salesforce')]"
    },
    "displayName": "[parameters('salesforce_conn_name')]"
  }
}
```

Comment: I have the same case as you. After searching for answers I found only these two tips:
[Salesforce Custom Domain/Sandobx](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/SECURITY/en-US/7ffffe1a-0991-447d-9673-9b8048db8c89/salesforce-connector-to-custom-domainsandobx?forum=azurelogicapps&forum=azurelogicapps)
 and [Logic App Deployment Connector](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/5d1e6232-06c2-4fb1-bb76-33afc733efef/logic-app-deployment-via-arm-template-authenticating-salesforce-sandbox-connector?forum=azurelogicapps). It seems that it is still not possible to do.

Answer (score 0):

You are not passing the parameterValues, use the below ARM template and it should work connecting to sandbox environment:

```
 {
      "type": "MICROSOFT.WEB/CONNECTIONS",
      "apiVersion": "2016-06-01",
      "name": "salesforceapiconnection",
      "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",      
      "properties": {
        "api": {
          "id": "[concat(subscription().id, '/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/', 'centralus', '/managedApis/', 'salesforce')]"
        },
        "displayName": "Salesforce API Connection",
        "parameterValues": {
          //The Salesforce Login URI. For Production, use https://login.salesforce.com
          "token:LoginUri": "[if(equals(parameters('environment'), 'production'), 'https://login.salesforce.com', 'https://test.salesforce.com')]",          
          "salesforceApiVersion": "v47",
          "privacySetting": "Organizational"
        }
      }
    }
```